# 'Sync-TcmSearchIndex' is not recognized

Tags: 2013-sp1, search

When I wanted to reindex the search for one of our clients running SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 I got following error when trying to run Sync-TcmSearchIndex:

The term 'Sync-TcmSearchIndex' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:9

- Sync-TcmSearchIndex <<<<

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Sync-Tcm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So I have 2 questions:

1. What can I do to fix the missing cmdlet?
2. Is there another way to trigger the re-indexation of the search?

Kr,

Thomas

Comment: did you try the answers? can you please mark the solution?

Comment: I did not have time to try out the answers yet. Once I have, I'll give the needed feedback.

Comment: any results? it's customary to mark a solution...

Comment: I know .. I gave feedback as soon as I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation the problem was found. During windows updates something went wrong with our machine which resulted in some functionality being dropped out of powershell. I do not know exactly what as this has been fixed by the IT department of our Client.

After the fix the Sync-TcmSearchIndex command was again available.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you with #1. I am not sure about #2. for #1,
check that you have the Tridion Automation dll. Inside your tridion install, you should have:

```
[Path to your install]\bin\PowerShellModules\Tridion.ContentManager.Automation\Tridion.ContentManager.Automation.dll
```

See if that exists. Next, check that your PSModulePath environment variable includes that directory. Mine looks like this.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;D:\opt\apps\tridion\bin\PowerShellModules\
```

Comment: btw, the SDL installer should have updated your environment variable for you automatically. we haven't done any manual configuration to make their PS commands work properly

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the command:

```
Import-module tridion.contentmanager.automation
```

After running this command run the sync command and it should work fine

Comment: shouldn't be necessary if you look at my answer, it should be imported if you include the dll in your modules--which should have been done by the Tridion installer

Comment: Indeed - since Powershell 3.0 import-module is automatically invoked if you invoke one of a module's commands